# Difference in PDF loading in lua- and xelatex

Tags: graphics, xetex, luatex, miktex

Someone is trying to install a package of mine (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lilyglyphs) in MiKTeX on Windows 7.

After some hassles with file and font paths we managed to get him going, but there is one strange issue left.

The package has a command that prints a PDF file from a subdirectory.
When compiling a document with LuaLaTeX the document is fine while with XeLaTeX doesn't print anything but preserves the space (the package relies on OpenType fonts, so it has to be compiled with one of these).

I find the portions from the logfile interesting:

XeLaTeX gives:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
File: lilyglyphs_logo.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "lilyglyphs_logo.pdf" > [1

]
```

while LuaLaTeX reports:

```
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
<lilyglyphs_logo.pdf, id=4, 40.40294pt x 14.79527pt>
File: lilyglyphs_logo.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
 <use lilyglyphs_logo.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: lilyglyphs_logo.pdf used on input line 5.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 39.1908pt x 14.35138pt.

[1

{C:/Users/Daniel/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <C:/local-t
ex-files/tex/latex/lilyglyphs/documentation/lilyglyphs_logo/lilyglyphs_logo.pdf
>] (C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/lilyglyphs-docs/luatex.aux) )
```

Seeing these different logs it looks quite clear that XeLaTeX doesn't print the PDF correctly, but I don't have a clue to why this happens.

Comment: I have no problem with `\includegraphics{../Downloads/lilyglyphs_logo}`both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Create a _complete_ minimal example, which shows that it doeesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Currently it somehow seems he "simply" has an issue with his installation in general. Otherwise I'll come back to you